# Java Selenium - How to Click a Button that has no ID or ng-class in AngularJS based page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

The following code I've used is not clicking the button and showing the error message.

```
WebElement clickNextButton = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-class='btn-success']"));
clickNextButton.click();
```

> Error message shows "no such element: Unable to locate element. {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[ng-class='btn-success']"}

I've also tried the following code segments without success:

1. ```
     WebElement clickNext1 = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[ng-class='pccCTRL.pow.Page1InputsValid() ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default'']"));
     clickNext1.click();
   ```
2. ```
    webDriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Next")).click();
   ```
3. ```
     webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='button']")).click();
   ```

Here is the screenshot showing the html code segment of the button I'm trying to

[image: Button code segment]

Hoping to get feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve this issue by using By.xpath

Here is the code segment that solved it:

```
WebElement clickNextButton = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Next')]"));

clickNextButton.click();
```