# How to find the element for following :<i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-class="getArrowClass($index)"></i>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to find the element for the beelow:

```
<i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-class="getArrowClass($index)"></i>
```

I tried :

```
int i = driver.findElements(By.className("getArrowClass($index)")).size();
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: class is not the same as ng class. [Have a look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272857/java-selenium-how-to-click-a-button-that-has-no-id-or-ng-class-in-angularjs-ba)

Comment: `getArrowClass` is probably computing the name for the real class, so you should use something like `driver.findElements(By.className("my-computed-class"))`